# How do I reverse the strings contained in each pair of matching parentheses, starting from the innermost pair? CodeFights

Tags: python, python-3.x

So far I have done this. I am stuck on recursion. I have no idea how to move forward, joining and reversing etc.

```
def callrecursion(s):
    a=s.index('(')
    z=len(s) - string[::-1].index(')') -1
    newStr=s[a+1:z]
# Something is missing here i cant figure it out
    print(newStr)
    return newStr

def reverseParentheses(s):  
    if '(' in s:
        return reverseParentheses(callrecursion(s))        
        print('wabba labba dub dub')
    else:
        return s
string='a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q'
reverseParentheses(string)
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT : "apmnolkjihgfedcbq"

Comment: Should the contents of a contained paranthesis also be flipped if the parent brackets are flipped? Or can you give an expected output for your specific example?

Comment: here is the output > "apmnolkjihgfedcbq"

Comment: Are the parens always going to be simply nested, or could you have something like `abc(def)ghi(jkl)mno`? In other words, can there be multiple sets of parentheses at the same level that are *not* nested?

Comment: it could be any combination if that's what you're asking..its a problem from codefights.com and they test the program with very complex test cases...

Comment: Another Expected input and Output :input>>     "The ((quick (brown) (fox) jumps over the lazy) dog)"    Output>>    "The god quick nworb xof jumps over the lazy"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def reverseParentheses(s):
    if '(' in s:
        posopen=s.find('(')
        s=s[:posopen]+reverseParentheses(s[posopen+1:])
        posclose=s.find(')',posopen+1)
        s=s[:posopen]+s[posopen:posclose][::-1]+s[posclose+1:]
    return s

string='a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q'
print(string)
print(reverseParentheses(string))
print('apmnolkjihgfedcbq') # your test

string='a(bc)(ef)g'
print(string)
print(reverseParentheses(string))
```

The idea is to go 'inward' as long as possible (where 'inward' does not even mean 'nesting', it goes as long as there are any opening parentheses), so the innermost pairs are flipped first, and then the rest as the recursion returns. This way 'parallel' parentheses seem to work too, while simple pairing of "first opening parentheses" with "last closing ones" do not handle them well. Or at least that is what I think.

---

Btw: recursion is just a convoluted replacement for `rfind` here:

```
def reverseParentheses(s):
    while '(' in s:
        posopen=s.rfind('(')
        posclose=s.find(')',posopen+1)
        s=s[:posopen]+s[posopen+1:posclose][::-1]+s[posclose+1:]
    return s;
```

(... TBH: now I tried, and the recursive magic dies on empty parentheses `()` placed in the string, while this one works)

Comment: It Works for all test cases ... I'm gonna need a minute to see what you did

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 2):

I've come up with tho following logic (assuming the parentheses are properly nested).

The base case is the absence of parentheses in `s`, so it is returned unchanged.

Otherwise we locate indices of leftmost and rightmost opening and closing parentheses
(taking care of possible string reversal, so `')'` might appear opening and `'('` -- as closing).

Having obtained `beg` and `end` the remaining job is quite simple: one has to pass the reversed substring contained between `beg` and `end` to the subsequent recursive call.

```
def reverseParentheses(s):
    if s.find('(') == -1:
        return s

    if s.find('(') < s.find(')'):
        beg, end = s.find('('), s.rfind(')')
    else:
        beg, end = s.find(')'), s.rfind('(')
    return s[:beg] + reverseParentheses(s[beg + 1:end][::-1]) + s[end + 1:]
```

Comment: Matched only 5 test cases..It failed on this string  "abc(cba)ab(bac)c" and "The ((quick (brown) (fox) jumps over the lazy) dog)"

Comment: The problem is with beg and end indices. I assumed you always have nesting, not siblings.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that number of opening and closing brackets always match, this might be the one of the simplest method to reverse words in parenthesis:

```py
def reverse_parentheses(st: str) -> str:
    while True:
        split1 = st.split('(')
        split2 = split1[-1].split(')')[0]
        st = st.replace(f'({split2})', f'{split2[::-1]}')
        if '(' not in st and ')' not in st:
            return st                

# s = "(abcd)"
# s = "(ed(et)el)"
# s = "(ed(et(oc))el)"
# s = "(u(love)i)"
s= "((ng)ipm(ca))"
reversed = reverse_parentheses(s)
print(reversed)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues in your code, and much of the logic missing. This adapts your code and produces the desired output:

```
def callrecursion(s):
    a=s.index('(')
    # 's' not 'string'
    z=len(s) - s[::-1].index(')') -1

    newStr=s[a+1:z][::-1]

    # Need to consider swapped parentheses
    newStr=newStr.replace('(', "$") # Placeholder for other swap
    newStr=newStr.replace(')', "(")
    newStr=newStr.replace('$', ")")

    #Need to recombine initial and trailing portions of original string
    newStr = s[:a] + newStr + s[z+1:]

    return newStr

def reverseParentheses(s):  
    if '(' in s:
        return reverseParentheses(callrecursion(s))        
        print('wabba labba dub dub')
    else:
        return s

string='a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q'

print(reverseParentheses(string))
>>>apmnolkjihgfedcbq
```

Comment: I know my logic is missing and its still fails to reverse "abc(cba)ab(bac)c" and "The ((quick (brown) (fox) jumps over the lazy) dog)"

Comment: @Abrar well you need to include the kind of input you expect this to solve in the question, otherwise we can't help.

Answer (score 1):

While the existing `O(n^2)` solutions were sufficient here, this problem is solvable in `O(n)` time, and the solution is pretty fun.

The idea is to build a k-ary tree to represent our string, and traverse it with DFS. Each 'level' of the tree represents one layer of nested parentheses. There is one node for each set of parentheses, and one node for each letter, so there are only `O(n)` nodes in the tree.

For example, the tree-nodes at the top level are either:

1. A letter that is not contained in parentheses
2. A tree-node representing a pair of parentheses at the outermost layer of our string, which may have child tree-nodes

To get the effect of reversals, we can traverse the tree in a depth-first way recursively. Besides knowing our current node, we just need to know if we're in 'reverse mode': a boolean to tell us whether to visit our node's children from left to right, or right to left.

Every time we go down a level in our tree, whether we're in 'reverse mode' or not is flipped.

---

Python code:

```py
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        self.children = []


def reverseParentheses(s: str) -> str:
    root_node = TreeNode()
    curr_node = root_node

    # Build the tree
    for let in s:

        # Go down a level-- new child
        if let == '(':
            new_child = TreeNode(parent=curr_node)
            curr_node.children.append(new_child)
            curr_node = new_child

        # Go back to our parent
        elif let == ')':
            curr_node = curr_node.parent

        else:
            curr_node.children.append(let)

    answer = []

    def dfs(node, is_reversed: bool):
        nonlocal answer
        num_children = len(node.children)

        if is_reversed:
            range_start, range_end, range_step = num_children-1, -1, -1
        else:
            range_start, range_end, range_step = 0, num_children, 1

        for i in range(range_start, range_end, range_step):
            if isinstance(node.children[i], str):
                answer.append(node.children[i])
            else:
                dfs(node.children[i], not is_reversed)

    dfs(root_node, False)

    return ''.join(answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the correct version for your `callrecursion` function:

```
def callrecursion(text):
    print(text)
    a = text.find('(') + 1
    z = text.rfind(')') + 1
    newStr = text[:a - 1] + text[a:z-1][::-1].replace('(', ']').replace(')', '[').replace(']', ')').replace('[', '(') + text[z:]
    return newStr
```

You probably have to take into account if the parethesis is the first/last character.

Comment: I Know that,thats why im here..I am new to Python..I need to rejoin the strings after reversing but doing that messes the indices of parentheses of innermost substring