# Reverse Parentheses

Tags: python, algorithm

I am doing reverse parentheses

```
def reverse_parentheses(s):
    """
    Reverse the strings contained in each pair of matching parentheses,
    starting from the innermost pair. The results string should not contain
    any parentheses.

    >>> reverse_parentheses('a(bc)de')
    'acbde'

    >>> reverse_parentheses(
    ...     'The ((quick (brown) (fox) jumps over the lazy) dog)'
    ... )
    'The god quick nworb xof jumps over the lazy'
    """
    chars = list(s)
    open_bracket_indexes = []
    for i, c in enumerate(chars):
        if c == '(':
            open_bracket_indexes.append(i)
        elif c == ')':
            j = open_bracket_indexes.pop()
            chars[j:i] = chars[i:j:-1]
    if open_bracket_indexes:
        raise ArgumentError('Unclosed parenthesis')
    print(''.join(c for c in chars if c not in '()'))
s = input()
reverse_parentheses(s)
```

[image: description1]

description1 what to do

[image: description2]

description2 what to do

[image: result]

result, 10th test always fails

I used a lot of algorithms, and they always fail on 10th.
There is the same issue was while ago:
StackOverFlow:
[seems like the same thing, but nothing works at 10th](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51101519/how-do-i-reverse-the-strings-contained-in-each-pair-of-matching-parentheses-sta)
LeetCode:
[the source code and a lot of others](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-substrings-between-each-pair-of-parentheses/solutions/2290806/python-sol-recursion-and-stack-sol-detailed-explanation-with-pictrue/)

used code:

[cyberforum](https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-tasks/thread3138023.html),

[leetcode-recursion_based_and_stack_solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-substrings-between-each-pair-of-parentheses/solutions/2290806/python-sol-recursion-and-stack-sol-detailed-explanation-with-pictrue/),
(literally other leetcode solution is like previous)

The cause of this issue in 90% is the "bad" test, that was poorly written, as long as this "problem" exists, there is links and answer below to this question

Comment: _which_ algorithms did you use that "failed"? Because a "dumb" DFA that starts a "reversed with respect to whatever we're doing right now" context any time it sees `(` and exits that context on `)` would get this right on the first go.

Comment: should i put them all in here? or just links to them?

Comment: You should [talk about them in your post](/help/how-to-ask). Hit the [edit] button, and then write up an explanation of which algorithms you tried, and what they resulted in.

Comment: I don't know that we need every failing attempt @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. They posted code that looks reasonable and is failing for some reason. That seems like enough to me. I, for one, can't find a failing test case for the posted code. I don't see how _more_ code that fails the same test contributes.

Comment: @mark7 In that case you have the power to click "close" and hit "cannot be reproduced" as reason (although of course it'd be a good idea to then also say that you copied and ran their code and that it ran just fine). However, if someone claims they tried multiple things, our posting guidelines tell them to talk about those, which will let _future visitors_ know whether or not this problem is theirs, as well.

Comment: @ASD I gave up trying to find a problem with your code. I submitted it to leetcode and it passed all tests. Where exactly are you running this that is failing?

Comment: That's fair @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans especially since the code seems to pass on leetcode. Not sure where this 10th test they are referring to is.

Comment: on yandex-contest. The organization that created this test is our 
ministry of education

Comment: Note that `chars[j:i] = chars[i:j:-1]` is not really symmetric, since the intervals are half-open. Easy to see if you print the result _with_ parentheses. Still, I don't see how it could lead to actual wrong answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution using `re` (I don't see it among the linked solutions). I've tested in on leetcode and it passes all tests:

```py
import re

s = "The ((quick (brown) (fox) jumps over the lazy) dog)"

while True:
    new_s = re.sub(r"\(([^)(]*)\)", lambda g: g.group(1)[::-1], s)
    if new_s == s:
        break
    s = new_s

print(s)
```

Prints:

```
The god quick nworb xof jumps over the lazy
```

---

[image]

Comment: still failed on 10th test

Comment: @ASD Well, then I'd question the test - if leetcode accepts it and this page not, something is wrong (maybe they supply wrong input(?)). I don't see error in my code (if the input is valid).

Comment: yeah, if still nothing maybe its the problem inside it

Comment: @ASD What  10th  test do you  mean? Leetcode provides only 4 tests for this problem.

Comment: i am doing it on https://official.contest.yandex.ru/, that test was developed by our ministry of education, and they chose this platform

Comment: @There  are no  tests at your link.  Only  compiler settings and errors values.

Comment: i can give you the auth page: https://official.contest.yandex.ru/contest/51338/problems/B/ but i belive you can do nothing with it. Of course i maybe could give you my auth data, but sorry you know, i cant

Comment: So __all__ solutions fall at at unknown and unreachable test 10. Why don't you address this problem to your ministry?